# ipod touch 5th generation crashed

Tags: ios, ipod-touch, crash

My ipod doesn't start anymore. I didn't drop it or anything like that... It just went black screen while I wasn't looking. I can't start it and charging doesn't do anything. What can I do?

Comment: Have you recently updated it?

Comment: Something you should try is plugging it into your computer (with iTunes).

Answer (score 1):

try pressing the home and off button at the same time for about a minute, or longer, and usually that will work. If not the battery may be dead. if it does not work try taking it to a tech shop. usually the first works with mine, still not sure why that happens though.

Answer (score 0):

Try plugging your phone into a computer with iTunes downloaded on it, open iTunes and see if your phone turns back on.